# Selecting row with id

Tags: mysql, .net

I've set up a database with 3 tables `grades`, `subjects` and `students`

Now, i don't know how to do a query to show them in the form

`Subjects`   `1st Q`    `2nd Q` `3rd Q` `4th Q`

`Science`     `grade` `grade` `grade` `grade`

`Math` `grade` `grade` `grade` `grade`

=================================

I have a subject_id for subjects table, id for students table and id, subject_id in grades table.

`id` of grades table is the child of `id` in students table.

`subject_id` of grades table is the child of `subject_id` in subjects table.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this query:

```
SELECT subject.name, grades.grade FROM subject INNER JOIN grades ON subject.id = grades.id_sub
```

With this query, you do an inner join between the table subject and the table grades